# Likelihood for dependent data conditioned on explanatory variables

Tags: time-series, probability, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

Let $Y_t$ be a $k\times 1$ vector of dependent variables explained by
\begin{equation}
Y_t=\beta'X_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t,\quad t=1,\cdots,T
\end{equation}
where $X_{t-1}$ is a $k\times 1$ vector of random variables. We assume that 
\begin{equation}
Y_t\mid \{X_{t-1}=x_{t-1}\}\sim\mathcal{N}(\beta'x_{t-1},\sigma^2)
\end{equation}

Furthermore, suppose that $Y_1,\cdots,Y_T$ are dependent. How can the likelihood function for estimating the parameters $(\beta,\sigma)$ be presented? When $Y_1,\cdots,Y_T$ are independent, I know how to express the likelihood function using recursions; however, in this case this seems more complicated.

Comment: You probably need to assume the Markov property as well?